# Inner Join query and interface based Projection in Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring MVC Project with Spring Data JPA running MySql DB, where I have four Entity Objects: Travel, Expense, Currency and Fund.

Here is a visual representation of my DB Schema:

[image]

In the ExpenseRepository interface I have extended the JpaRepository interface.

Now I am trying to run a native SQL Query where I will pass the expenseId and I will fetch expense and amount from the Expense table and currency_name from the currency table. (You can see i have to do two inner joins to get the currency_name.)

finally I have created another interface ExpenseOutput to consolidate the three columns into a separate non-entity interface (As per the Interface based projection mapping mentioned in the Spring Data JPA Documentation).

Here are the codes:

```
package com.binarycraftbd.ksktravelbackend.Repo

import com.binarycraftbd.ksktravelbackend.JoinQueries.ExpenseData
import com.binarycraftbd.ksktravelbackend.Model.Expense
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query

interface ExpenseRepo : JpaRepository<Expense, Int> {


    @Query("select expense, amount from expense, currencyName from currency inner join fund on expense.fund_id=fund.id inner join currency on fund.currency_id=currency.id where expense.id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    fun getCurrencyByExpId(expId:Int): ExpenseOutput

    interface ExpenseOutput{
        fun getExpense():String
        fun getAmount(): String
        fun getCurrencyname(): String
    }
}
```

However, when I am running the code via a RestController function, I am getting the following error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Sep 22 20:51:25 BDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I am also giving the Entity Classes here:

Travel Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "travel")
class Travel(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        val id: Int=0,
        val travelName: String="",

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "travel")
        @JsonIgnore
        val funds: List<Fund> ?= null,

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "travel")
        @JsonIgnore
        val expenses: List<Expense>?=null

)
```

Currency Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
class Currency(

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        val id: Int=0,
        val currencyName: String="",

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "currency")
        @JsonIgnore
        val funds: List<Fund>?=null
)
```

Fund Class

```
@Entity
class Fund(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        val id:Int=0,
        val fundName:String="",

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fund")
        @JsonIgnore
        val expenses: List<Expense>?= null,

        @ManyToOne
        val travel: Travel?=null,

        @ManyToOne
        val currency:Currency?=null
)
```

Expense Class

```
@Entity
class Expense(


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        val id:Int=0,
        val date:String="",
        val time:String="",
        val expense:String="",
        val amount:String="",
        val category:String="",

        @ManyToOne
        val travel: Travel?=null,

        @ManyToOne
        val fund: Fund?=null
)
```

How to solve this problem?  Is it incorrect to write the query codes in the ExpenseRepository? or is there something wrong with the Sql query?  Pease HELP!!

Comment: `SQLGrammarException` suggests faulty query syntax

Comment: I have corrected the SQL query as per Mohammed Hassan's suggestion.  Still it's not solved

Answer (score 0):

Econ try to run this query in any sql client like mysql workbench for instance before embedding it in the code.

i re-write the query above like below, i found some syntax errors and non logical stuff.

```
select expense.expense, expense.amount, currency.currency_name  
from expense inner join fund on (expense.fund_id=fund.id)
inner join currency on (fund.currency_id=currency.id)
where expense.id=<replace this segment with a valid expenseId>
```